# Should I cross-post on MO?

Tags: support, specific-question, mathoverflow, cross-posting

About two months ago I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414967/lt-ip-is-a-well-defined-well-ordering-of-iterable-set-premice) on MSE and I have gotten no answers ever since. I also put some bounties on it and if I try to put more bounties on it I think I will lose some of my privileges, so that's not a good option.

But on the other hand I don't know whether my question can be considered as a research-level question. Maybe it qualifies, but I don't know.

Is it okay to try my luck on MO? Because I think there might be some inner model theorists there that could help me out.

Also if it is okay to do so in this case, may I know what steps should I take towards cross-posting it, so I won't break any rules?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26960/is-it-ok-to-ask-a-question-from-stackexchange-again-on-overflow https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26203/reposting-on-math-overflow-which-practice-is-best https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25343/migrating-questions-the-simple-way https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/cross-posting-or-flag-for-migration

Comment: Re: "what steps should I take towards cross-posting". Some basic advice on cross-posting can be found on this meta - see [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) - and also on MathOverflow Meta in [this answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se/2638#2638).

Comment: @Asaf, that's what I get for not searching beforehand. Sorry. Since I can't flag for a migration, I have decided to cross-post. I have a question. Do you think I should cut the parts which I show my own ideas and go straight for the question, or should I post it as is? I will add the necessary information regarding the cross-posting of course.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thanks for the links. In the first link, it is mentioned that if I receive an answer there, I should somehow mark it for migration. I don't understand what that means. When I get an answer on MO, what should I do to migrate that answer to MSE?

Comment: @Asaf, I ask this because I am not familiar with MO's "culture". And I don't know whether it is best to explain my thoughts or I should go straight to the point and not waste time.

Comment: If you get an answer on MO, the advice given here seems reasonable: [What to do with my cross-posted question that got answered elsewhere?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27641) It is true that Willie Wong's answer mentions also [migration](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/migration/info) as a possibility - however, a question cannot be migrated if it is older than 60 days.

Comment: I'd think your specific question is fine for MO, and we can either migrate it as it is, or you can cross-post (and put links).

Comment: @Asaf, So migration is an option? I thought it was not possible for questions that were asked more than 60 days ago. If it is possible, then I'm okay with that.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I overlooked the date.

Comment: @Asaf, Oh, so I'll try to think this through and I will post it tomorrow. Thanks for the help!